# Do transformers need cross-validation

Tags: neural-networks, classification, cross-validation, natural-language

I am trying to train a NLP text classification model using HuggingFace's Transformer package. I have noticed that they do not provide a cross validation function and couldn't find any example of people training BERT models and doing cross validation. I was wondering if there may be a reason that these models wouldn't need CV.

Thank you